# I have this list with x and y coordinates that are in interval of [-2,2]. But when I plot the list, x exceeds the value of 2 by far. Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
clist=[(-1.2720626442476508, 0.023952387163360456),
      (1.509233613482305, -1.196551723413994),
      (-0.37776845297034178, -1.9620288805522699),
      (-0.95028695770255522, -1.5670871848691932),
      (-0.19286972570683192, -1.2638500626369975),
      (1.19847548993563, 0.32781113190011446),
      (-0.93998357957640977, 0.74954973932266267),
      (-0.65151553614971647, -0.65350263688351395),
      (-0.65151553614971647, -0.65350263688351395)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2, 200), ylim=(-2, 2))
plt.plot(clist,'ro')
plt.show()
```

As you can see the x coordinate exceeds the value 2. The y coordinate is right.

[image: as you can see, the x coordinate exceeds the value 2]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image of code, so people can copy and paste it.

Comment: Try dividing the x and y coordinates into two separate arrays or list. x = [] y = [], then plt.plot(x,y)

Comment: One way to prepare separate lists is like so: `plt.plot([x for x,y in clist], [y for x,y in clist], 'ro')`

Comment: here's a hint: there are 16 dots on your figure and 8 unique coordinate pairs in your list.

Answer (score 7):

`plt.plot(array)` will plot an array of assumed y coordinates over a sequence of x coordinates. You'll need to explicitly pass `plt.plot(xdata,ydata)` to plot correctly.

In this case `plot(array)` is taking your input to mean: (y-value, y-value) at x = 0, (y-value, y-value) at x = 1, etc.